# Detect whether system supports an alpha channel (via wxWidgets)

Tags: wxwidgets, alphablending

I've got a wxWidgets program. For one piece of it, I want to use an alpha channel to "fade" a set of icons if the system supports alpha-blending, and grayscale them if it doesn't, but I can't seem to find any way to tell whether the system supports alpha-blending or not.

Is there something I'm missing, or is there no wxWidgets and/or cross-platform way to do this?

(I'm fairly well conversant with wxWidgets, but I've never done alpha-blending before.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From what I can tell, you call `CanSetTransparent` on a top-level window, and if it returns `true`, call `SetTransparent` with a value < 255. If *that* returns `true`, then the system supports alpha transparency. You must do this *after* the top-level window you're working with is shown.

(`CanSetTransparent` just checks the OS version under Windows, always returns `true` under Mac OS, and checks both the compile-time GTK version and a function on wxGTK. `SetTransparent` takes different paths on Windows and GTK depending on whether the value is 255 or something less.)